# Swift: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift2

I have JSON data from website. I made the main dictionary and I can parse every data except one sub dictionary. I get the error "Swift: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' to 'NSDictionary'"

This example of my data. I cannot parse **"weather"** but I can parse all other dictionaries like `"wind"`.

```
   ["name": Mountain View, "id": 5375480, "weather": (
        {
        description = "sky is clear";
        icon = 01n;
        id = 800;
        main = Clear;
    }
), "base": cmc stations, "wind": {
    deg = "129.502";
    speed = "1.41";
```

Snippet of code

```
 let windDictionary = mainDictionary["wind"] as! [String : AnyObject
 let speed = windDictionary["speed"] as! Double
 print(speed)
 let weather = mainDictionary["weather"] as! [String : AnyObject]
 print(weather)
```

Comment: It seems it is an array, not a dictionary. Try
 let weather = mainDictionary["weather"] as? [AnyObject]

Comment: weather is not dictionary.... `let weather = mainDictionary["weather"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]`

Comment: But wind dictionary with the same syntax

Comment: @ElCaptain is right i think

Comment: if you take a look, wind only has {} after it, what is a dictionary in a JSON. However weather has ({ }) what means the dictionary is wrappend in an array.

Comment: Yes, @EICaptain is right. Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

on behalf your comment...I would say windDictionary is Dictionary...

```
Dictionary denotes in JSON with {} and 
Array denotes with [] // In printed response you may have array with ()
```

So, your weather part is Array of Dictionary...You have to parse it like

```
 let weather = mainDictionary["weather"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]  // although please not use force unwrap .. either use `if let` or `guard` statement
```

Comment: No it's ok, it's much better now. Thanks for editing. :)

Comment: Thanks Man, I was looking for something like this. :)