# how to parse complex json data in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I am new to iOS and I want to parse data but it is so complex, I don't know how to parse it. Below given is the json data.

```
{
    "response_code": 200,
    "last_updated": {
        "date": "2015-12-27",
        "time": "01:32:13"
    },
    "trains": [
        {
            "train": {
                "number": "04921",
                "start_time": "04:45",
                "name": "SRE-UMB MEMU SPECIAL",
                "type": "HSP"
            },
            "dest": {
                "code": "UMB",
                "name": "AMBALA CANT JN"
            },
            "source": {
                "code": "SRE",
                "name": "SAHARANPUR"
            }
        },
        {
            "train": {
                "number": "04922",
                "start_time": "20:45",
                "name": "UMB-SRE MEMU SPECIAL",
                "type": "HSP"
            },
            "dest": {
                "code": "SRE",
                "name": "SAHARANPUR"
            },
            "source": {
                "code": "UMB",
                "name": "AMBALA CANT JN"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what you feel is complex in this ... can you elaborate

Comment: `trains` is an array, `train , dest and source` is dictionary

Comment: [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123797/swift-could-not-cast-value-of-type-nscfarray-to-nsdictionary/33123953#33123953)  for better idea

Comment: `var responseObj = JSON.parse(jsonresponse);`

Comment: El Captain v2.0 I know how to parse simple json data. As I am knew to iOS I don't know how to parse multiple dictionary at same time.

Answer (score 0):

`{ , , }` - it's a dictionary
`[ , , ]` - it's an array

In your case you get:

First level - dictionary with keys `response_code`, `last_updated`, `trains`.
Where:
`response_code` - value
`last_updated` - dictionary with keys `date`, `time`
`trains` - array of dictionaries with keys `train`, `dest`, `source`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSJSONSerialization) class, it's easy.

For example, in Objective-C:

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
if (jsonObject) {
   // jsonObject is an NSArray or NSDictionary representation of the data that you can now do something with
}
```