# parsing JSON with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I'm coming from android programming to Swift iOS programming and have a hard time parsing a json 
here's String I try to parse :

```
{"response":[{"uid":111,"first_name":"someName","last_name":"someLastName","photo_100":"http:someUrl/face.jpg"}]}
```

here how I try to parse this :

```
 if let dict = Utils.convertStringToDictionary(response)! as? [String: AnyObject]{
       //  this part is yet doing ok
       if let response = dict["response"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
           NSLog("let response \(response)")
           if let first_name = response["first_name"] as? String {
                NSLog("first_name = \(first_name)")
           }
        }
        else {
            NSLog("not an []")
        }
```

the Log message gives me "not an []" as it can't make a response object. As far as I understand, I'm doing right as `[String: AnyObject]` is what is in "response" body of my json

Just in case, here's my Utils.convertStringToDictionary method:

```
public static func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
            return json
        } catch {
            NSLog("Something went wrong")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: your "response" parameter is array not dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Array in swift denotes with []
Dictionary in swift denotes with [:]
your response parameter is array of dictionary ... so it denotes with [[:]]
```

so just parse it with `[[String: AnyObject]]`

```
if let response = dict["response"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
     for user in response{
         NSLog("let response \(user)")
         if let first_name = user["first_name"] as? String {
              NSLog("first_name = \(first_name)")
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: could you please give me an explanation on this double square braces in [[String: AnyObject]] ?

Comment: Thanx a lot! so, response is actually an array of dictionaries, right?

Comment: yes ... in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33123953/4601170).. I did explain what brackets, braces in JSON suggest what ... it may be helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Problem here is response is an `array`

```
if let response = dict["response"] as? NSArray{
   for value in response as? NSDictionary{
      print(value["uid"]) /// prints 111
      print(value["first_name"]) /// prints someName
   }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to parse it then? I kind of confused as in fact it's a HashMap<String, Object> in terms of Java , but here it's an array - how do I get Value for Key?

Comment: i've added my answer and added parsed example

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if let dict = Utils.convertStringToDictionary(response)! as? [String: AnyObject]{
      //  this part is yet doing ok
      if let response = dict["response"] as? NSArray{
         NSLog("let response \(response)")

         for dict in response{

             if let first_name = dict["first_name"] as? String {
                 NSLog("first_name = \(first_name)")
             }
         }                      

      }
      else{
           NSLog("not an []")
     }
}
```