# Extract JSON data which is stored in dictionary

Tags: json, swift, xcode

```
["Subscriptions": {
StudentData = "<null>";
SubscriptionsData =     (
            {
        AcademicYear = "2015-2016";
        DataBasePath = "abc";
        Institute = xyz;
        IsCentral = 1;
        IsExists = 0;
        SubscriptionId = 1059;
    }
);
UsrData =     {
    "EmpNum_AdminNum" = C001;
    Id = 1;
    Name = "Vamshi ";
    RoleName = "p_staff_superadmin";
};
}]
```

I am new to swift and unable to extract particular parameter like "dataBasePath"

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33123953/4601170 .. this might helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can get databasepath in string using this

```
if let subscriptionsData = result["SubscriptionsData"].arrayObject as Array<AnyObject>!
                    {
                        if let item = subscriptionsData[0] as? [String: AnyObject]
                        {
                            if let dataBasePath = item["DataBasePath"] as? String
                            {
                                print(dataBasePath)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Subscriptions is "result".

Answer (score -1):

```
if let subscriptionsData = Subscriptions.objectForKey("SubscriptionsData") as NSArray {

     if let subscriptionsDataDictionary = subscriptionsData.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary {
             let DataBasePath = subscriptionsDataDictionary.objectForKey("DataBasePath") as? String
            }
     }
```